# WPF: How can I create a reusable Form Template?

Tags: wpf

Is there any possible way to create a reusable form template which I can initialize it with different content like controls in WPF?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, there is.  Unfortunately, your question is much too general to provide a good answer.

Comment: http://homepages.tesco.net/~J.deBoynePollard/FGA/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html

Comment: @Will. what are the posibility?

Comment: very possible.  I think the language barrier is preventing you from asking an answerable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with any `Window` - just set its `DataContext` to the appropriate data.  As long as the property names in the data match up, the bindings will all still work.

That being said, this is more commonly handled by making a [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx).  This allows you to compose portions of your UI in a reusable manner, and put these in other UserControls or Windows as needed.